# Delete request in mongodb not working, I am using an expressjs server and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to send a delete request to delete an item by id in mongodb but t isnt working. I've searched and tried several stackoverflow solutions with no success.

I have tried:

```
app.delete('/delete', (req,res) => {
    var id = req.params._id;
    var objectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId
    MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true}, (err, db) => { 
        if(err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("MusicPlayer");
        dbo.collection("Musician").deleteOne({"_id": new mongodb.objectId(id)}, (err, result) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            db.close();
            res.redirect('/')
        });
    });
})

And :
app.delete('/delete', (req,res) => {
    var id = req.params._id;
    var objectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId
    MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true}, (err, db) => { 
        if(err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("MusicPlayer");
        dbo.collection("Musician").deleteOne({"_id": mongo.objectId(id)}, (err, result) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            db.close();
            res.redirect('/')
        });
    });
})

app.delete('/delete', (req,res) => {
    var id = req.params._id;
    var objectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId
    MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true}, (err, db) => { 
        if(err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("MusicPlayer");
        dbo.collection("Musician").deleteOne({"_id": objectId(id)}, (err, result) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            db.close();
            res.redirect('/')
        });
    });``
})
```

I am not getting errors in the console nor is the console actually logging anything, even simple strings.

Comment: Is the code reaching the route?? (Add console.log to the very first line of the route).
Also Verify that record exists for the id and also try to console.log(result)

Comment: Nothing shows when I console log

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this after you are sure the request hits the router?
You are reading id from req.params, so you must include :_id in the route url.

Also I think ObjectId must be ObjectID.
And you should use {"_id": new objectId(id)} in deleteOne.

```
app.delete('/delete/:_id', (req,res) => {
  console.log(req.params);
  var id = req.params._id;
  var objectId = require("mongodb").ObjectID;
  MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true}, (err, db) => { 
      if(err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db("MusicPlayer");
      dbo.collection("Musician").deleteOne({"_id": new objectId(id)}, (err, result) => {
          if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
          }
          console.log(result);
          db.close();
          res.redirect('/')
      });
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks now I just get an error saying I must pass in a single string of 12 bytes.

Comment: @TEbogo What did it console.log(req.params)?

Comment: {Id: _id}  and I get an error argument passed must be a single string of 12 bytes or 24 hex characters

Comment: @TEbogo you need to pass a valid 24  character mongo id from your client like:

axios.delete("/delete/5d409684384c9a2c30f66268")

Comment: and your console.log(req.params) must console something like this {"_id" : "5d409684384c9a2c30f66268")

Comment: I don't understand what you mean axios.delete(...)

Comment: The id is coming from user input and I'm copying it as is from mongo and still get the error

Comment: @TEbogo Show the code, where you are calling this api

Comment: It just seems like I'm inputting the string 'id' and I'm not

Comment: add the code please so I can check. But I think the problem in this question is already resolved.

Comment: app.delete('/delete/:_id', (req,res) => {
  console.log(req.params);
  var id = req.params._id;
  var objectId = require("mongodb").ObjectID;
  MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true}, (err, db) => { 
      if(err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db("MusicPlayer");
      dbo.collection("Musician").deleteOne({"_id": new objectId(id)}, (err, result) => {
          if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
          }
          console.log(result);
          db.close();
          res.redirect('/')
      });
  });
})

Comment: It's exactly how you showed me except id is being read as the string id and not the actual id. NotI'm sure if it's the input or what. This my first api

Comment: please test the api with postman,  I think you just need to pass the correct id from your app to this route. If with postman it works, the route is ok, and you can consider to accept my answer,   then you can open a new question with your html application.